# Smallest size of the transposition table that still makes sense

Tags: engines, transpositions

I've implemented a chess engine with iterative deepening, triangular table for PV and aspiration window. The engine runs on a microcontroller with 1MB of RAM. I read in the Internet everything I could find about the transposition table but could find any papers saying how small can it be to still make it benefficial for the search speed.

Currently I have no more than ~440kB I could spend on it, would it still give me some bonus or it's better to stick with the PV based on the triangular table in that case?